# How to update multiple fields with one click in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am tasked with creating an LWC that will update five fields on the Account object. The LWC only needs to contain one simple button with a heading. The button needs to be displayed only if certain criteria is met by the values on that particular Account Record. I am new to creating LWCs and coding in general. This is what I've come up with right now. The update button is not working and is asking for a required field 'Name'. The conditional rendering(disable/enable) of the button is not working too. Please help me and let me know where I am screwing up. I've crawled through blogs and modules, but it's all a little confusing since I am a beginner.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom11" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            &nbsp; Client Reactivation
        </h3>
        <div class="slds-text-align_left">
            <p>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This button becomes available when Account is eligible for reactivation.
            </p>
        </div>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
            <lightning-messages>
            </lightning-messages>
            <template if:false={hideBtn}>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-button
                        class="slds-m-top_small"
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        name="update"
                        label="Reactivate Client">
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:true={hideBtn}>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-button
                        class="slds-m-top_small"
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        name="update"
                        label="Reactivate Client"
                        disabled=true>
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </template>        
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import PISA from '@salesforce/schema/Account.PI_Software_Access__c';
import ASTAT from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Account_Status__c';
import DTBA from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Data_to_be_anonymized_date__c';
import RDATE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Retirement_Date__c';
import AOH from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Account_On_Hold__c';
import AOHR from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Account_On_Hold_Reason__c';
const fields = [PISA];
export default class AccHexUpdateButton extends LightningElement 
{
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [PISA, ASTAT, RDATE, DTBA, AOH, AOHR] })
    account;
    hideBtn;
    get PISAc() 
    {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, PISA);
    }
    handleSuccess(event) 
    {
        this.Id = event.detail.recordId;
    }    
    handleSubmit(event)
    {
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        fields.PISA = true;
        fields.DTBA = null;
        fields.RDATE = null;
        fields.ASTAT = 'Active';
        fields.AOH = false;
        fields.AOHR = null;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
     }
    handleChange(event)
    {        
        if(this.PISAc == false)
        {
            this.hideBtn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.hideBtn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can see that might help you.

First of all, the function that you are using to toggle the hideBtn attribute isn't being called from anywhere which is why that functionality won't be working. If you want this to be called when the component is loaded or when the form is submitted, you will need to make sure that you call that method from the handleSuccess (which is called when the form is successfully submitted and a record is created) and when the wire method you are using to retrieve the recordId on load.

In terms of the update button, this is throwing an error because the form thinks that you are trying to create a new record. You need to pass the lightning-record-edit-form tag the Record Id of the Account you are wanting to update. Without this Id, it will always attempt to create a new record. This behaviour should be covered in the 'Editing a record' section of the lightning-record-edit-form documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

Comment: Callum, thank you so much for pointing out the errors. Just one question, shouldn't the function be called regardless of a success event? The rendering would depend on the prior value of the field before I update it

Comment: That is definitely one way of doing it. The issue that you might have though is that you're essentially saying that the component values are the source of truth. If you call the rendering function even on failure, you will accidentally disable the button when it shouldn't be. I wouldn't expect that to happen unless the record was actually updated if that makes sense?

Comment: The values are actually based on the current value of the record. So I am saying that the record values are the source of the truth. Some business context, if the Account is active there's no need to show this 'Reactivate' button.

Comment: When you call the handleSubmit function, you're explicitly setting the values that are stored within the component. That means that on a failed submission, those values won't reflect the actual state of the record. The @wire method will only be called on initialisation of the component so that is the only time that you'll actually be retrieving the values from the record.